# Sticky footer with flex-box and main body with overflow:auto breaks on non-webkit browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox, microsoft-edge

I have designed a web-page with a header and a sticky footer as follows:

```css
/* 
    Created on : Nov 16, 2017, 12:39:01 AM
    Author     : pantelis
*/
body, html {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    background-color: #173a61;
    font-family: sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial; 
}

body.sticky {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column; 
    
    height: 100vh;
}

/* classes */
p {
    margin: .5em 0;
}
a, a:visited, a:active, a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #81afd2;
}
a:hover {
    color: darkblue;
}

/* general */
header, footer, section, div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: .5em;
}

header, footer {
    background-color: #b8d0ea;
    text-align: center; 
}

header h1, footer h1 {
    margin: .4em; 
}

main {
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: white;
}

/* movies */
#movies {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 50%;
    overflow:auto;
    border-right: thin solid silver;
}

figure {
    text-align: center;
    margin: .8em .8em;
    width: 90px;
}

img {
    width: 92px; 
    border: none;
}

/* movie */
#movie {
    width: 50%;
    
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
}

#movie img {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 200px;
}
#header {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border-bottom: thin solid silver;
}
#details {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}
#details p:first-of-type {
    font-weight: 600;
}
#footer {
    border-top: thin solid silver;
}
```

```html
<body class="sticky">
        <header id="main-header">
            <h1>Test Flex</h1>
        </header>
        <main>
            <section id="movies">
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            </section>
            <section id="movie">
                <div id="header">
                    The Title
                </div>
                <div id ="details">
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                </div>
                <div id="footer">
                    The footer
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
        <footer>
            The Footer &copy;
        </footer>
    </body>
```

The `footer` is properly positioned at the bottom of the browser window using the following CSS:

```
body.sticky {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;

    height: 100vh;
}
main {
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;

    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
                flex: 1;

}
```

Two sections, each of 50% width, are contained in the `main` body. The first one contains many small items, so it is also a flex-box:

```
#movies {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;

   width: 50%;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

The other section contains details of the movie upon clicking each item in `#movies`.

When `#movies` is empty, or with few items, all browsers render the page properly. When it is loaded with many items,
*Chrome* and *Safari* and all other *webkit* browsers (*Opera*, *Vivaldi*) display the page as expected, i.e. the `#movies` item displays a scroll bar without any expansion and the footer remains in place at the bottom of the viewport, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnZKI.jpg). (Note that scrollbars are not shown on a Mac.)

*Firefox* and *Edge* on the other hand do not render the page as expected: the `main` section is expanded all the way down along the y-axis in order to contain all the items in `#movies`, **no scrollbar** is shown. The footer goes down too, after the end of `#movies`.

The issue can be tested [here](http://boubouni.com/flex/). I would welcome any ideas that might help to remedy this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex item's has, in this case for column direction, a `min-height` that defaults to `auto`, which prevents it to become smaller than its content.

For Firefox and Edge, this needs to be set to `0` on the `main`, or else it will simply grow/overflow with its content.

```
main {
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: white;
    min-height: 0;                        /*  added  */
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
/* 
    Created on : Nov 16, 2017, 12:39:01 AM
    Author     : pantelis
*/
body, html {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    background-color: #173a61;
    font-family: sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial; 
}

body.sticky {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column; 
    
    height: 100vh;
}

/* classes */
p {
    margin: .5em 0;
}
a, a:visited, a:active, a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #81afd2;
}
a:hover {
    color: darkblue;
}

/* general */
header, footer, section, div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: .5em;
}

header, footer {
    background-color: #b8d0ea;
    text-align: center; 
}

header h1, footer h1 {
    margin: .4em; 
}

main {
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: white;
    min-height: 0;                        /*  added  */
}

/* movies */
#movies {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 50%;
    overflow:auto;
    border-right: thin solid silver;
}

figure {
    text-align: center;
    margin: .8em .8em;
    width: 90px;
}

img {
    width: 92px; 
    border: none;
}

/* movie */
#movie {
    width: 50%;
    
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
}

#movie img {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 200px;
}
#header {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border-bottom: thin solid silver;
}
#details {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}
#details p:first-of-type {
    font-weight: 600;
}
#footer {
    border-top: thin solid silver;
}
```

```html
    <body class="sticky">
        <header id="main-header">
            <h1>Test Flex</h1>
        </header>
        <main>
            <section id="movies">
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            the movies<br>
            </section>
            <section id="movie">
                <div id="header">
                    The Title
                </div>
                <div id ="details">
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                    The details<br>
                </div>
                <div id="footer">
                    The footer
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
        <footer>
            The Footer &copy;
        </footer>
    </body>
```

Comment: @PantsMookie Perfect...and may I ask you to also accept the answer.

Comment: Not sure how but I think I did: I clicked on the tick mark on the left of the answer